# How can pass parameter in ng-model like ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have some problem to make get data without click some button. In my html I give ng-click to get data from http.get but if without ng-click I cannot get data.
This my **HTML**

```
 <ion-list>
        <ion-item class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="repeat in rep">
            {{jk}}
            <div>
                <img class="img-responsive" ng-src="https://omg-indonesia.com/2017-06-15.png" />                    
            </div>
            <div>            
                <select ng-options="size as size.code for size in sizes"
                        ng-model="item"
                        style="background-color:#262261;color: white"
                        ng-change="update(item)">
                </select>
            </div>   
            <button type="submit" ng-click="kk(repeat)"></button>
            <p>Hasil trip history untuk tanggal {{repeat | date: "dd-MM-y"}}</p>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

and this **JS**

```
    $scope.kk = function (repeat) {
        kaka.list($scope.item.code, repeat).success(function (data) {
            console.log(repeat);
        });
    };
    $scope.jk = function (repeat) {
        kaka.list($scope.item.code, repeat).success(function (data) {
            console.log(repeat);
        });
    };
```

My issue is, when I click button `console.log(repeat)` in `kk` have data from http.get but in `jk` no data in `console.log(repeat)`, is there anyone who can help me? Thanks

Comment: if you want to show the elements from `repeat`, just replace `{{jk}}` with `{{rep}}`. change `repeat in rep` with `rep in repeat`

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not calling the function,

change it as,

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="kk(repeat);jk(repeat)"></button>
```

Comment: can i call function without click button

Comment: <ion-item class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="repeat in rep" ng-init="jk(repeat);">

Comment: it work but if i have 30 lists it show all data jk in list

Comment: use limitTo directive

Answer (score 0):

in your case `jk` is a function with required parameter `repeat`. You should provide this parameter to function, otherwise inside function it will be `undefined`

Try this: `{{ jk(repeat) }}`

Answer (score 0):

Just as @Sajeetharan said.

No function calls here. `{{ jk }}` is only going to output the value of `$scope.jk` if it is an object/string/integer etc and not invoke a function.

Take a look at this from the angular [Developer Guide for templates](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/templates).